# Exponential and convergence in $L^2$ bis

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

This question is a  continuation of my question "Exponential and convergence in $L^2$" posted above:

Let $(f_k)$ be a sequence of elements of $L^\infty(\Omega)$, which converge in $L^2(\Omega)$ to $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. Where $\Omega $ is an open bounded subset of $R^n$. **Assume that $e^{f_k}\in L^2(\Omega), \; k\ge 1$ and $e^{f} \in L^2(\Omega)$.**

Is it true that  : 
$e^{f_k} $ tends to $e^f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\Omega=(0,1)$,
$$
f_n(x) = \chi_{[0,1/n]} n^{1/4}.
$$
Then $f_n\to0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. And
$$
\|e^{f_n}\|_{L^2(\Omega)^2}= n^{-1} e^{2n^{1/4}} + 1 - \frac 1n\to \infty,
$$
so it holds $e^{f_n}\in L^2(\Omega)$, $e^f\in L^2(\Omega)$, but $(e^{f_n})$ cannot converge in $L^2$ as it is unbounded.

---

As it turns out, even uniformly boundedness of $(e^{f_n})$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ is not enough:
with
$$
f_n(x) = \chi_{(0,e^{-n})}(x) \frac n2,
$$
it holds
$$
\|f_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = e^{-n} \frac {n^2}4 \to 0,
$$
so $f_n \to f$ with $f=0$,
and
$$
\|e^{f_n}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = e^{-n} e^n + (1-e^{-n}) \to 2 \ne 1 =\|e^{f}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 .
$$
Hence $(e^{f_n})$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2(\Omega)$ but cannot converge to $e^f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

---

Under the additional assumption that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded in $L^\infty(\Omega)$, you can prove the desired convergence by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appriciate your counter examples. I think that in the first case, $\|e^{f_n}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2=n^{-1} e^{2n^{1/4}}+(1-1/n)$, but this does not affect the rest.

Comment: @rabat corrected the answer